# Multiple subscriptions per transaction in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, subscriptions

Is it possible to edit the way woocommerce currently processes subscription products to allow for multiple subscriptions to be purchased at once? Stripe recently announced that they can now handle multiple subscription checkouts, yet woocommerce won't be able to for a long time. Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if anyone has solved this yet or if there is a plugin that works with woo-commerce subscriptions etc... I would love to have multiple subscriptions in one transaction. All of my subscriptions are a 3-month duration anyways so the whole order would be the same subscripion time respectivly.

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternative Subscriptions extension that allows multiple subscriptions per transaction:
http://codecanyon.net/item/subscriptio-woocommerce-subscriptions/8754068